# Stata equivalent of array

Tags: stata, matrix

I've been trying to solve this problem reading different material but I just can't figure it out. It's pretty simple and takes about 5 seconds to do in languages that work with arrays, but I can't work it out in Stata.

Please ignore the substitution of the backticks in some places, I couldn't get them to appear correctly. 
Let's say I have an ID variable and, among others, variables that show me whether a person has company or is alone and whether he drinks alcohol or not. If someone has company, I have a variable showing me how many these companions are and who they are (by their IDs in the data set). I'm trying to see if these companions drink alcohol and do a repetitive process with that info. Obviously in Stata if the companion has ID 345 I can't use the form alcohol[345] because that gives me the alcohol state of the observation 345, not of the ID 345. Is there a similar form in Stata?  I can only list it by doing
list alcohol if id==345.
What I want to do is take these IDs and pass them on into a repetitive process that allows me to see whether all of these companions don't drink alcohol, part of this process is to have a variable d which I modify for every companion who does not drink alcohol (i.e. when the variable alcohol is not 1). I do the following, if m is the number of companions (let's say two here) and comp'k'`x' are the IDs of the companions of the person with ID k (let's say ID 8 here) :

```
gen d = .  
local m = 2  
local k = 8  
forvalues x= 1/'m' {   
 replace d = 'x' if alcohol[comp'k'`x'] !=1  
}
```

so for example the first companion of person with ID 8 would have ID comp81= 345, the second comp82=567. But of course this code does not do what I want, for the reason above.

The following will give me the alcohol state of the person whose companions are IDs comp81 and comp82, and not what I want which is the alcohol state of these companions:

```
. local m=2  
. local k = 8  
. forvalues x= 1/'m' {  
2. list alcohol comp'k'`x'  
3. }
```

And the following doesn't work either:

```
local m = 2  
local k = 8  
forvalues x= 1/'m' {  
2. list alcohol if id==comp'k'`x'  
3. }
```

I don't just want to list the alcohol state of the companions, but the above are examples to show that I can't find the Stata equivalent of an array and use it to solve the problem I have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for Stata code. Please review advice on software-related questions in the Help Center. This would go better on Stack Overflow (which averages about 1 Stata question per day) and even better on Statalist (which averages many more).

Comment: As a question on coding this suffers because we can't be sure of your real code (i.e. whether you are using different single quotation marks for local macro references, as is required); you don't say what "doesn't work" means; you don't show an example of your data to make your structure crystal clear (an example listing is worth many hundred words in description).

Comment: I already wrote "Please ignore the substitution of the backticks in some places, I couldn't get them to appear correctly", the macro references in my original code are written correctly. Doesn't work means it doesn't execute, because the value in comp`k'`x' is not passed onto id as I'd like it to. I did describe what my variables are.

Comment: I know you wrote that, but it doesn't help any readers. The bigger point is that you should get good help elsewhere, but you're quite off-topic here in my view.

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example with `auto.dta` data set to find the companions of a car that have the same `mpg` value, and figure out whether they are `foreign` or not.

```
set more off
sysuse auto, clear
local N = _N
* create an id variable
gen int id = _n
* paranoid check
isid id
* create place holder for the companion char variable
gen byte companion_anyforeign = 0
forvalues n=1/`N' {
   * figure out who else has the same values of MPG
   * this gives you the list of IDs
   levelsof id if mpg == mpg[`n'] & id != id[`n']
   * check if there are any companions at all
   if "`r(levels)'" != "" {
     * now go over that list and figure out if they are foreign
     foreach k of numlist `r(levels)' {
        * poor man's lookup
        sum foreign if id == `k', mean
        * there should be only one such case
        assert r(N) == 1
        * update the companion status
        replace companion_anyforeign = companion_anyforeign | r(max) if id==id[`n']
     }
   }
}
```